# How to track training loss for scikit-learn logistic regression?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

For context, I'm trying to optimize the `max_iter` (and potentially `tol`) parameter(s) of `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression`.

Right now I'm training with `max_iter=5000`, which is very slow. To get an idea of whether this is necessary, rather than just changing `max_iter` ad hoc and seeing if the results are similar, I'd like to actually see **how the loss evolves over each training iteration and what the model predicts during each iteration**. For instance, if it takes 534 iterations to converge, but after 400 iterations the prediction stops changing, I might increase my tolerance or lower the number of iterations.

However, I see no way of doing this -- while I can see the number of iterations until convergence in the `n_iter_` attribute, I don't actually get loss values for those iterations. If I call the `predict()` method on the training data, my understanding is that it will then apply the trained-model, not recall the actual information from training.

Can anyone tell me how I can retrieve the loss and predictions on each training iteration?

Due to some peculiarities of my dataset/setup I implement cross validation from scratch, so the only sklearn method called for training is the one below (called once per split).

Thanks in advance!

```
logreg = make_pipeline(
                LogisticRegression(
                    random_state=42,
                    C=.06,
                    penalty="l1",
                    max_iter=5000,
                    solver="saga"
                    ))

logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: did you solve this? as far as i can see there is no way of viewing the iterations.

Comment: Nope. https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/26494